# How to change types in a TypeScript class based on an object property of a parent class?

Tags: typescript, discord.js

For a project, I've two classes:

- `ParentClass`
- `childrenClass` that extends the `ParentClass` class

Here is the code of my `ParentClass`:

```js
interface ConfObj<T extends boolean> {
  enabled: T;
  permissions: bigint[];
  location: string;
}

interface HelpObj {
  name: string;
  description: string
  category: string;
  id: number;
}

interface ParentClassType<T extends boolean> {
  conf: ConfObj<T>;
  help: HelpObj;
}

type ParentClassParameters<T extends boolean> = HelpObj & ConfObj<T>;

class ParentClass<T extends boolean> {
  conf: ConfObj<T>;
  help: HelpObj;

  constructor({ enabled, permissions, location, name, description, category, id }: ParentClassParameters<T>) {
    this.conf = {
      enabled, permissions, location
    };
    this.help = {
      name, description, category, id
    }
  }
}
```

After that, in the `ParentClass` construtor, I just assign the good values to the class properties.

So, in the `childrenClass` now, I extends then `ParentClass` with the required informations. I want that if the value of `ParentClass.conf.enabled` is set to true, the type of a parameter of the `ChildrenClass` class is modified.

I tried this code (for the children class):

```
interface AChildrenParameterInterface<T extends ParentClass<any>> {
  isEnabled: () => boolean;
  name: string;
  description: string | (T["conf"]["enabled"] extends false ? undefined : never);
}

class ChildrenClass extends ParentClass<true>  {
  constructor() {
    super({
      enabled: true,
      permissions: [],
      location: '',
      name: '',
      description: '',
      category: '',
      id: 0
    });
  }

  run(data: AChildrenParameterInterface<ChildrenClass>) {
    return data.description;
  }
}
```

So in this example, if we set the `ParentClass` value to `true`, I want the `data.description` type to be equal to `string`. And if enabled is set to `false`, then type `data.description` will be equal to `string | undefined`.

I don't know if everything is clear, but I'll try to explain as best I can.

I'm doing a minimal reproducible example here: [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQwPICMBWyA3gFDLnIQhy4A2EAJgFzK7rr1wgDcZFADtAC2wAM6jgmUS1zAA5qDABtALq8KyWugRwwkkC1FgooObwC%20JEoujwkyABIRa-PIVIbqQiIeOn1FAwQoggm-HqYviYgZnzkOpBy6FAAnlH%20ccjAzMggAK5CuNAWVjawiCgACnBQVGCotHDiACopgsSZCJgwLBhYbgHkABbO-CxOLgMkliRgbVU1dQ1NotVQcN6QUKLIALyOo27IAGRo3VMkCI3iyGtL1zseyF1YvecEASMu44cfVvFSYx5BBgZIACiIlGodEYABpkIIoCJxPpRPCtAl9PCvBB4UEQmEIiB4QkIElUvDsshzCw7uBluI1hsIFtRABKDoachgIZiAB0Lxge05XPIVBo9AY8MRyIkUnR2l0%20ky5HMgwoPP5X34wqeopxeOCoWA4Sxz10ZOSKUpDBV1L4lhmAHonc9AVwwMgYFB0EJkFx0DzoJpgLh1qlrOBbBVkABBVC82gMWogJmbaAASSj5XsTzEAFFoZKWGCObsAHysdicHh8HHpGIBfHG02RZBGaJyZAAH2QeRAQRgoEYJSsc3aABEUl5gAgE8AkynWu19vPF1QGaIlAByQXblQ78Uwhj7ygAD0gA52QIgmQA-MgwXbyNgRGAADzxxPJqhplmZ7M7FxZBtwLItGG3StjmfEVRQ0ZtCX0BtYjg%200NA5FgvwXH9UxqZktizLYgN4SMiJjNccOXFA9WQKB%20xLMpECJFgpxnOdvyXeYy0rLgUlHS4HjQDiN0EiALyoBgdjpepBOAIR%20HobxwB2CjOPaJ4Xg7YFQSgUtYPbPJEQhO0j2LZAb1hO0ZTEOUQGkZBVEs0UMSVNtt23JyuXrECPLtBCTWYnzPI0UlyTSIK7WyFgAAZMnMNkAhmcg6JAR8GF0OBMNU388PTKBCOjJA2WQ-TajAPIoFS9KwDgPl-NbWtVWmIA). The `run` method of the `ChildrenClass` should have no error, without making a condition or changing the type of the return method.

Comment: Please [edit] to put your [mre] as plaintext in the question itself.  A playground link is a nice supplement but it doesn't suffice by itself.  I'd do it myself but copyright issues are tricky and it's not clear that anyone but you has the rights to copy the code to which you are linking.

Comment: (see prev comment) What do you mean "without changing the type of the return method"?  You've annotated it as `string`.  If someone changes `conf.enabled` to `false` don't you want the return type to be `string | undefined` instead?  Right now the closest I can think of to what you're looking for is [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7V8rw), but it's clunky... mostly because I think your constraint isn't very easily expressed.  Does that at least behave the way you're looking for, or am I missing something?

Comment: So, actually, I didn't mention it but the `conf.enabled` value is static (it can't be changed during runtime). My question was just to see if anyone had a solution to prevent the team I work with from changing the type every time they set enabled to `true` or `false` in the constructor.
If we don't have a solution, it's not a problem, we can change both the type and the value.

Comment: Note that the word "static" has a different  and important meaning in JS/TS (and OOP in general): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static.
The word you are looking for is "immutable": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Immutable

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the exact thing you're asking for is possible, because `conf.enabled` can change at runtime:

```
const foo = new childrenClass();
foo.run(data) // you want data.description to be typed as string
foo.conf.enabled = false; // you want `run()` type to change, it can't
```

You could probably just drop `ChildrenType`:

```
class childrenClass extends ParentClass implements ChildrenType<true> {
  constructor() {
    super({
      enabled: true
    });
  }

  public run(interaction: Omit<AChildrenParameterInterface, "isEnabled"> & { description: string }): any {
  }
}
```

You *could* use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#handbook-content), but I doubt it will be very useful.
This example probably doesn't quite fit your needs, but I'd need to see more of your code to know.

```
export interface ParentClassType<T extends boolean> {
  conf: ConfObj & {enabled: T};
  help: HelpObj;
}

interface ChildrenType<T extends boolean> extends ParentClassType<T> {
  run: (interaction: T extends true ?  (
    Omit<AChildrenParameterInterface, 'isEnabled'> &
    {
      description: string;
    }
    ) : AChildrenParameterInterface) => any;
}

class childrenClass implements ChildrenType<true> {
  constructor() {
    super({
      enabled: true
    });
  }

  public run(interaction: Omit<AChildrenParameterInterface, "isEnabled"> & { description: string }): any {
  }
}
```

Comment: In fact, the `conf.enable` can't change during the runtime (like any other variable in the conf object).
In fact, these answer are good, but as I wasn't clear in the question, it's normal that you suggest them to me. I'm more interested in an automatic way for everything to adapt according to the value of the variable, rather than having to change the type of input each time.

Comment: It doesn't matter that `conf.enable` can't actually change at runtime; TS resolves a type for the `run()` parameter at compile time, so `enabled` needs  to be decided at compile time as well. That's where generics usually come in - to tell TS "`ChildrenType` is a `ParentClassType` where enabled has to be `true`". But in your case you'll still have a lot of boilerplate, which I think is what you want to avoid.